# How to install any.apk file use terminal command on Android 10 and higer version devices

Tags: android, terminal, apk

I install .apk file on Android 10 and higer version devices like this:

```
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install -t -r /data/user/0/com.company.example/files/test.apk")
```

But for some reason it cannot be installed. Please tell me how to install any apk files by terminal commands on Android 10

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: Apk file cannot be installed